# How do I find the program to associate with a file on the web?

Tags: 12.04

I'm not so good at wording questions, but I'll try and explain it.

On a website webupd8.org, there are some orange boxes that has "available on the Sofware Centre" written on it. When I click on it I get the "Launch Application" dialogue box.

Assuming that it is like clicking on a link for the google play store that opens up the play store app on your phone, I hit "Choose" to look for the "ubuntu software center". I can't find it though.  Am I looking for the wrong thing?

How to I make manual file associations in the future?

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu Firefox Modifications addon enabled in firefox? Either check in about:plugins or Tools menu > Addons.

Comment: Yes, it's installed and active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to use the "Lauch Application" dialogue box to create file associations.  Another way to do get to the dialogue in the future is to right click on the file of interest and choose "open with".

The ubuntu-software-center handles .deb file types, and would be what you would want to look for if the link was directly to a .deb file.

However, in this case you to open that can handle 'apt:' uris.  This program is called apt-url which on a standard Ubuntu install can be found at:

```
 /usr/bin/apturl
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried just typing it in but it didn't work. I was probably doing it wrong but I found it under /usr/bin/.

Comment: strange that usually works; I'll update my answer accordingly.